# C++. Why I can't compile this code? What is wrong with removing constness using const_cast?

Tags: c++, const-cast

I have some problem removing constness using const_cast. Error msg says "Conversion is a valid standard conversion....."

What is the nature of this problem? Why should I use C-style cast instead?

"error C2440: 'const_cast' : cannot convert from 'const size_t' to 'size_t'"
"Conversion is a valid standard conversion, which can be performed implicitly or by use of static_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast"

```
template<typename T>
const IFixedMemory* FixedMemoryPkt<T>::operator=(const IFixedMemory* srcObj)
{
    // doesn't remove constness this way. why?
    const_cast<char*> (this->m_Address) = (char*)srcObj->GetAddress();

    // compile this way, but maybe(?) undefined behaviour
    // const_cast<char*&> (this->m_Address) = (char*)srcObj->GetAddress();

    // doesn't doesn't work too
    const_cast<size_t> (this->m_Size) = (size_t)(srcObj->GetSize());
    // const_cast<size_t> (this->m_Size) = 0;

    return this;
}

template<typename T>
class FixedMemoryPkt : public IFixedMemory
{
private:
    const size_t m_Size;
    const char*  m_Address;
}

class IFixedMemory
{
public:
    virtual const char* GetAddress() const = 0;
    virtual size_t GetSize() const = 0;
}
```

Comment: So your *fixed memory packet* is not so fixed after all? From the name, it seems to me that this class should not be copyable / assignable.

Comment: Your object doesn't have a `m_Memory` member. Please, post real code, not fake one.

Comment: Or anyway, please compile the fake code for yourself before posting, to confirm that it shows the same problem as the real code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`const_cast` is used to convert from pointers or references to `const` objects, to their non-`const` equivalents. However, you can't use them to modify the object they refer to if the object itself is `const`. There is no valid way to modify `m_Size`; if you want to modify it, then don't declare it `const`.

You do not need a cast to assign to the pointer, since the pointer itself is not `const`:

```
this->m_Memory = srcObj->GetAddress();
```

If you did want the pointer itself to be `const`, then the `const` would come *after* the `*`:

```
char * const m_Address;
```

and, as with the `const size_t`, you wouldn't be able to reassign it.

As the error says, you can convert a `const` *value* into a non-`const` *temporary copy* of that value without a cast; but you couldn't assign to that temporary.

Comment: But the code resulting from `const_cast<size_t&>(this->m_Size) =` has undefined behavior (modifying the const-qualified data member `m_Size`), so there's more wrong with the questioner's code than just that it doesn't compile.

Comment: @SteveJessop: Good point, it's too late on a Friday to think properly about this.

Comment: Thanks Mike! In this case I tried to add overloaded operator= for some convenience... Originally those members were set only thru constructors. Now I see that I need to change some design... Otherwise I'll get some troubles in runtime.

Comment: I just replaced "const size_t" with size_t. Don't see any reason to be const. And as you said pointer m_Address is not const, it just points to const memory - so I'm good

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to cast the size_t thing to an r-value, and you can't assign to an r-value.

I have to say that casting away the constness of your size_t member is pretty evil. That's what mutable is for. And AFAICS your 1st const cast does nothing useful.

Comment: You don't need `mutable` here, just remove the `const`. `mutable` is for when you need to modify it from a `const` member function.

Answer (score 0):

Works this way now...

```
template<typename T>
const IFixedMemory* FixedMemoryPkt<T>::operator=(const IFixedMemory* srcObj)
{
   this->m_Address = srcObj->GetAddress();
   this->m_Size = srcObj->GetSize();
   return this;
}

template<typename T>
class FixedMemoryPkt : public IFixedMemory
{
private:
    const char* m_Address;
    size_t      m_Size;
};
```